# how to concat a $ to a particular string

Tags: mysql, sql, string

this is my program in output there is $ will not printed.
i will use correct syntex as '$'+ but it doesn't work

```
SELECT USERS.ID,CONCAT(USERS.FIRSTNAME,' ',USERS.LASTNAME)AS USERNAME,
     ('$'+ SUM(CPS_HISTORY.CHARGED_AMOUNT+CPS_HISTORY.TRANSACTION_FEE+CPS_HISTORY.SERVICE_CHARGE+CPS_HISTORY.COMBO_PAK_PRICE))AS REVENUE FROM USERS JOIN CPS_HISTORY ON CPS_HISTORY.SUBSCRIBER_ID = USERS.ID GROUP BY USERS.ID ORDER BY REVENUE DESC LIMIT 5;

+---------+---------------+---------+
| ID      | USERNAME      | REVENUE |
+---------+---------------+---------+
| 1803399 | Michael Rowan |     772 |
| 1697091 | NULL          |     676 |
| 1790000 | ree Green     |     626 |
| 1766654 | Jose M NUFIO  |     625 |
| 1731854 | Ashlee Durgin |     622 |
+---------+---------------+---------+
5 rows in set, 13305 warnings (0.15 sec)
```

the problem with concat function is: changed data.

```
+---------+-----------------+---------+
| ID      | USERNAME        | REVENUE |
+---------+-----------------+---------+
| 1753814 | Joseph Hearn    | $99     |
| 1806377 | Gideon Anderson | $99     |
| 1800992 | Camryn Revitte  | $99     |
| 1802344 | Tanner Chik     | $99     |
| 1594358 | NULL            | $99     |
+---------+-----------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Change upcase to locase.

Comment: @AvinashRaj And then?

Comment: To all the downvoters: What's the point? Didn't you understand the question?

Comment: @glglgl why are asking me? And i'm not the downvoter.. I  won't downvote a new user's post, whatever mistakes he/she made.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I didn't claim you are. I just ask you what would be the point of changing to lowercase.

Comment: @glglgl i think the downvotes is because of uppercase. So i asked him to change the case.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Ah, now I see! In the original version it was all uppercase. Ok, then it is clear, then I would have downvoted too... I wonder what makes people create SUCH UNREADABLE POSTS...

Answer (score 1):

use concat to concatinate the values:

```
SELECT USERS.ID,CONCAT(USERS.FIRSTNAME,' ',USERS.LASTNAME)AS USERNAME,
     concat('$', SUM(CPS_HISTORY.CHARGED_AMOUNT+CPS_HISTORY.TRANSACTION_FEE+CPS_HISTORY.SERVICE_CHARGE+CPS_HISTORY.COMBO_PAK_PRICE))AS REVENUE 
     FROM USERS JOIN CPS_HISTORY ON CPS_HISTORY.SUBSCRIBER_ID = USERS.ID GROUP BY USERS.ID ORDER BY REVENUE DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: It will print not a correct answer of sum. The value of sum is changed. and remain same in all rows. so there is problem with concat() function.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question and the table description of both tables?

Comment: i add it in my question.

Comment: @KunjanShah Please add also the recodrds from your table `CPS_HISTORY ` and `USERS` so i can check whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The data is not changed, only the type.

You are ordering by your `REVENUE` column, which was numerical before, but now, after the `CONCAT()`, it is a string. And `$99` as a string comes before `$772` (if sorted DESC).

There are two solutions:

1. Add the `$` in your application instead in SQL, or
2. Work with a sub query which does the data picking and ordering in the inner query and the formatting in the outer one.

   Something like

   ```
   SELECT ID, USERNAME, CONCAT('$', REVENUE) AS REVENUE FROM
       (SELECT USERS.ID,CONCAT(USERS.FIRSTNAME,' ',USERS.LASTNAME) AS USERNAME,
       SUM(CPS_HISTORY.CHARGED_AMOUNT+CPS_HISTORY.TRANSACTION_FEE+CPS_HISTORY.SERVICE_CHARGE+CPS_HISTORY.COMBO_PAK_PRICE)) AS REVENUE
       FROM USERS JOIN CPS_HISTORY ON CPS_HISTORY.SUBSCRIBER_ID = USERS.ID
       GROUP BY USERS.ID ORDER BY REVENUE DESC LIMIT 5) AS INNER
   ```

   should do. (Untested!)